# cents per gallon to gallons per person - regression intepretation

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

**Equation:** *fuel = B0 + -7.441gatax*

*fuel: motor fuel uses in (gallons per person)*

*gatax: state gas tax in (cents per gallon)*

How would you explain a 1-unit increase in the gas tax?

thanks for any help interpreting this.

Comment: The question is asking: How much does fuel increase or decrease when gatax is increased by 1?

Comment: fuel is the states annual per person use of motor fuel in (gallons per person) and gatx is the states gasoline excise tax rate in (cents per gallon). fuel is the dependent variable (y) and gatax is an independent variable (x) in an mlr regression equation.

Comment: Calculate fuel when gatax is any number (e.g. 4) and then when it is one unit higher (e.g. 5).  Then do the same thing for another pair (say 50 and 51). This should tell you what the effect is when you change one unit.